# How to do chatbot performance testing

Tags: performance-testing

Can anyone please suggest me how to do performance testing for azure Bot Service and also suggest me which tool will best suited for chatbot performance testing.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Looking into [How bots work](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-basics?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp) article it is quite enough to send normal [HTTP POST](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/POST) requests using JMeter's [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler in order to simulate real users talking to the bot:

[image]

You should be even able to record the requests from your browser/application to the Bot Controller, you should be interested in the ones which have `api/messages` in their Path. The requests can be recorded using either JMeter's built-in [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html) or [JMeter Chrome Extension](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/the-new-blazeMeter-chrome-extension-v4-easily-script-jmeter-and-selenium/)